# Dynamic breadcrumbs on Ng Zorro

Tags: angular, breadcrumbs, ng-zorro-antd

How can I change dynamically breadcrumbs?
I have channels inside of channel I want to change breadcrumbs to Channel / [channel name].

I'm using auto breadcrumbs:

```
<nz-breadcrumb nz-col nzFlex="auto" [nzAutoGenerate]="true"></nz-breadcrumb>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **nz-breadcrumb** from **ng-zorro** UI component library (currently version 10.2.1) does not support dynamic paths. You can achieve this by manually changing a name of a route item in Angular router when the route changes in your application.

```js
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.router.config
    // ... change the name of routes based on received parameters
  });
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a library that have it already implemented i.e [ngx-breadcrumbs](https://github.com/udayvunnam/xng-breadcrumb).

```js
import { BreadcrumbService } from 'xng-breadcrumb';

constructor(private breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    breadcrumbService.set('@<alias>', '<breadcrumb label>')
  });
}
```